# как импортировать модуль

Tags: python

дерево проекта

```
project/
   first/
      __init__.py
      mainModule.py
   __init__.py
   need.py
```

как импортировать need.py в mainModule

Comment: from project.first import need

Answer (score 0):

Так можно указать то, что надо импортировать или `*` для всего:

```
from first/mainmodule import *
```